# Restrict full control user to view a particular page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spuser

I have a sharepoint site http://spp/sitepages/page2.aspx

I have a group called "Group1" with full control. There are two users "User1" and "User2".
So both the users will have full control and both of them can make any changes in page2.aspx. Now this is my requirement, I want to allow only "User1" to access, when "User2" access my page I want to show "Access Denied" is it possible without code.

Assume I have 100 users, and want to restrict 1 user. It can be done by adding the 99 users to my permitted area. But instead of adding that 99 users, simply I just want to add that 1 user in my restricted area. Like in my mobile I have block calls option. The blocked list can't make a call to me. Is there any option like that in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

I think only way you can achieve this is by breaking role inheritance on that particular item, removing your group from item permissions and grant user1 full control and user2 read permission by hand.

If You have users in group with higher permission level in group, and by hand try to restrict them access to an item/site/page, sharepoint chooses highest possible level for that user, so restricting doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is adding a `location` entry to the web.config, denying access to a specific path for specific users / groups. This is only necessary when you want to restrict access to pages not in the virtual file system, i.e. layouts pages etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't using check in/check out be better suited for this?  You wouldn't get the flashy access denied page, but it would show you the page is checked out for editing by another user.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to restrict access with SharePoint ootb features is Application Policies in Central Administration. Create Permission policy then assign it to User policy. But it's only working on Application level, not on list/item level, so my answer is "custom code only"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bump of an old post, but if someone is interested in doing this, there is another option **if security is not your main concern**

Audiences are used to show web parts for only specific people.  If someone knows how to navigate SharePoint, they can still get to that content, but it takes away the easy option.

You would create a web part that contains an access denied message.  Set the audience of this to the restricted users.

Then, create a content editor web part that contains CSS that hides all of the other web parts.  Set the audience of this web part to the restricted users.

If the person is a restricted user, they get the access denied content editor web part, as well as the CSS content editor web part, which hides all the others.

[More Details](http://abbijohn.blogspot.com/2012/07/sharepoint-hide-web-part-for-selected.html)